# Should didReceiveResponse always be called for NSURLSessionUploadTasks with custom delegates?

Tags: delegates, ios7, nsurlsession

I'm investigating using NSURLSessionUploadTasks to manage the background uploading of a few files. The session is created using:

```
_urlsession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:identifier] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

This is created within a class that conforms to `URLSessionDataTaskDelegate`, and specifically defines:

```
– URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:
– URLSession:dataTask:didBecomeDownloadTask:
– URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:
```

And logs to the console each time one of these delegates is called.

Then, an upload task is created with the following code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?filename=%@", HOST, UPLOAD_PATH, filename];
NSMutableURLRequest *attachmentUploadRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
attachmentUploadRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[attachmentUploadRequest addValue:@"application/binary" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionTask* task = [_urlsession uploadTaskWithRequest:attachmentUploadRequest fromFile:filePath];
task.taskDescription = 'upload';
```

However, the sequence of delegate callbacks that I get is not as expected:

```
URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:]:196: Respond with <NSURLCredential: 0x1cf4fe00>:
URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:]:282: Task 'upload' sent 32768 bytes
URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:]:282: Task 'upload' sent 48150 bytes
URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:]:222: Task 'upload' got some data:
```

Notably, the body data is sent, as expected, but then it switches immediately to `didReceiveData` delegate callbacks, with no `didReceiveResponse` callback beforehand. This is an unexpected behavior for me: I'd expected to receive information about the response so that I can properly set up data, or better yet, convert the task to a download task to save the response to a file.

If the upload task is submitted in a default URL session, then didReceiveResponse is called, and I can successfully convert the task to a background download task.

I can't find any indications in Apple's documentation for whether or not `didReceiveResponse` should be called for `NSURLSessionUploadTask`s that are in the background. It *seems* that they should: the documentation for `NSURLSessionUploadTask` indicates that it is a subclass of `NSURLSessionDataTask` with small modifications in behavior, but neither of the listed differences involves not sending the `didReceiveResponse` callback. None of the background-session-specific docs mention this limitation.

Is this a bug, or have a missed/misinterpreted some piece of the documentation that explain that upload tasks in the background do not call `didReceiveResponse`?

Answer (score 6):

I asked Apple engineers about this during recent Tech Talks.  They followed up and gave the following response - not entirely satisfactory, and I feel like they should document this behavior if it is different than any other HTTP handling flow.  Especially since the foreground behavior does get the didReceiveData, but doesn't get the didReceiveResponse.   At the very least they need to document this non-obvious behavior.

"The way things work today is that we don’t send the didReceiveResponse callback for background uploads to avoid waking the app if it’s not already running.  The drawback is that the app cannot choose to convert the background upload into a download task when the response is received.  Our decision was based on expecting the response data for a file upload would be small and therefore delivering the response data to the client as NSData instead of a downloaded file would be fine."

Comment: What happens if a non-200 response is received and the body is empty? How are we expected to receive and handle this response? If there is data, can we assume that didReceiveData is called only once? This is a pretty major departure from the life cycle of every other delegate-based HTTP handler on the platform. All of the differences should be clearly documented and explained.

Comment: Update - I got a response from Apple that I should test it again in iOS 8.  So I tried, and it didn't work. So I went to the developers, since I was at WWDC and told them the fix didn't work. It turns out the fix was a comment in the header that says it doesn't work (which is an improvement).  I got some background on why they did it that way, but I still think they could as a courtesy call the didReceiveResponse and make it more consistent. I'm still campaigning for it.

Comment: @JasonLeBrun If I'm understanding your question correctly, in that circumstance you'd get a URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: callback on your delegate, with the response in task.response. (That's in the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate protocol, the "parent" protocol of the one you've implemented.)

Comment: This (undocumented) feature wasted four hours of my time. I wish Apple would fix this.